# Page not found error 404 with django framework

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm developing website for my resume using django framework and for styling i am using uikit css framework but facing problem with the url for contact template as it throws "page not found error"

```
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/contact/

Using the URLconf defined in myresume.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    experience
    education
    contact
    admin/

The current path, contact/, didn't match any of these.
```

i have tried using re url pattern and also trailing slash as mentioned in the official documentation. Contact template is available at myapp/templates/myapp/contact.html

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.home),
    path('experience',views.experience),
    path('education',views.education),
    path('contact',views.contact),

]
```

i am expecting to render contact template in my browser

Comment: You should add a trailing slash to your paths, so `'experience/'`...

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem i have also tried that but when i open in browser when i am accessing education or contact page it follows ```experience/educatio```n path

Comment: that is likely because that is not your `ROOT_URL` config.

Comment: here is my project named resume urls.py file

Comment: here is my project named resume urls.py file 
```from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('resume.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Comment: Try http://localhost:8000/contact without a slash at the end

Comment: Hi @Rarblack as you suggested i made changes but no luck as still it following ```experience/education/contact``` path when i click on a hyperlink

Comment: here is my uikit  dotnav template
```<div class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-medium uk-position-fixed">
<ul class="uk-dotnav uk-dotnav-vertical">
    <li class="uk-active"><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="education">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Connect</a></li>
</ul>```

Comment: have you configured templates folder in settings? Maybe Django isnt finding the html pages at all.

Comment: Please if you want us to help accurately, we are not going to in comments, add everything related to your problem in the question itself and we will help

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. I have resolved the issue by editing the HTML template as <a href=/experience, /education and / contact respectively